# What are the best perfmon counters for an ASP.net application?

Tags: asp.net, perfmon

What are the best performance monitors one can set to monitor an asp.net application?

I don't have direct access to the server in question, so I sort of have to explicitly ask for certain things other wise they do not happen. My hunch is that my app pool is restarting, but I want to get to the bottom as to why this is occurring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b4d4d195-2ecb-4728-9348-6f1bfa1a1b63.mspx?mfr=true) is the MSDN listing of the important perfmon counters for IIS.

If your site is restarting, you'll also want events from the Application and Security logs relating to IIS.

You can also use [IISState](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/993a8a36-5761-448f-889e-9ae58d072c09.mspx?mfr=true) to generate a dumpfile if/when a crash does happen.